# How to convert m3u8 file to mp4 video using nodeJS with a remote S3 input

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

The objective is to convert .m3u8 file(hls stream) to .mp4 video inside my NodeJS application. I've tried doing the same using `ffmpeg` on console and that works fine but unable to find a recently maintained package that helps me do this in node.
Also, my input file is not the usual file located in my local directory but a remote AWS S3 object URL which is otherwise accessible to all(public bucket), in simpler words,

How do I do `ffmpeg -i https://mycloudfrontURL/myHLSfile.m3u8 output.mp4` in JS?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use `ffmpeg` directly in your node.js application.

Install `ffmpeg` on your pc. Then create a node.js file that runs `ffmpeg` like so:

```js
const { execSync } = require('child_process')

const input = 'https://mycloudfrontURL/myHLSfile.m3u8'
const output = 'output.mp4'

execSync(`ffmpeg -y -i "${input}" "${output}"`)
```

You'll be able to execute `ffmpeg` and get the same result as if running it from the terminal. Make sure to have `ffmpeg` installed or indicate the full path if it doesn't work.

If this worked for you, upvote the solution.